# Can I represent the following schedule using a CRON expression?

Tags: cron

I'm trying to represent the following schedule using a `CRON` expression:

```
Every Sunday at 9:00 pm <br/>
Every Monday at 6:00 am and again at 9:00 pm <br/>
Every Tuesday at 6:00 am and again at 9:00 pm <br/>
Every Wednesday at 6:00 am and again at 9:00 pm <br/>
Every Thursday at 6:00 am and again at 9:00 pm <br/>
Every Friday at 6:00 am<br/>
```

Comment: I believe this is not possible with one expression - you'll need to use two, or have some initial code to check if it's Sunday at 6am or Friday at 9pm and stop/cancel the job.

Comment: Two expressions will do it.  `0 0 6 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *` and `0 0 21 ? * SUN,MON,TUE,WED,THU *`.  As @qJake said, it doesn't seem possible with one.

Comment: I'll throw an answer on here too, just for documentation/historical purposes. Thanks for verifying my assumption was correct, @Gene!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to express this schedule using a single cron expression.

You'll need to use two cron expressions, one for the 6am runs, and another for the 9pm runs.